# Hovering effects in html & css are working improperly

Tags: html, css, image, hover

Wondering if anyone can help out. I am building a site page called "services". I have a column of images - upon hovering a mouse over image, the image should become semi transparent and in the center, a text box with service name should appear. Transparency feature works fine, but upon hovering a mouse over each image, the service name is displayed only on the first top image. See below my html & css code. Thanks in advance :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>John Smith</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/services.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="../public/img/logo.png" id="logo">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a class="active" href="home.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
            <a href="about.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-id-card"></i> About</a>
            <a href="projects.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-code-o"></i> Projects</a>
            <a href="services.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-files-o"></i> Services</a>
            <a href="contact.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:15%; width:100%"><h1><i>Services</i></h1></div>
        <hr style="width:50%">


        <div class="col1">
            <img src="../public/img/productDesign.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">Product Design</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col1">
            <img src="../public/img/graphicDesign.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">Digital Graphic Design</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col1">
            <img src="../public/img/webDev.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">Web Development</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col1">
            <img src="../public/img/genProg.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">General Programming</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col1">
            <img src="../public/img/network.jpg">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">Networking and OS</div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

//CSS:

```
.col1 {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.col1 img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;

    opacity: 1;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.col1:hover img {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
  }

  .col1:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .text {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure about your problem. but it is most likely the `position: absolute`.

as you never define a `position: relative` for the parent, `position: absolute` always refers to the next actively positioned parent element. and that is in your case the body element. so the absolute positioned element is always at the same position.

to solve that give each `col1` the style of `position:relative`